# Mongoose Model.remove callback isn't giving me count of items deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So basically I have a model that when I call remove on it, the return is an object that I can't access.

Right now when I call remove I want to access the number of items removed and I am unable to.

This is what is returned:

```
{
'ok': 1
'n': 0
}
```

this is not what I want. I figured out that n is the count, however when trying to access it via count.n I can't.

Here's my remove code

```
Shift.remove({
        _id: req.body.id
    }, function(err, count){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({success: false, message:'problem with id'});
        }else if(!err && count === 0){
            res.json({success: false, message:count});
        }else if(!err && count === 1){
            res.json({success: true, message:count});
        }
    });
```

I've tried

```
Shift.remove({
        _id: req.body.id
    }, function(err, count){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({success: false, message:'problem with id'});
        }else if(!err && count.n === 0){
            res.json({success: false, message:count});
        }else if(!err && count.n === 1){
            res.json({success: true, message:count});
        }
    });
```

and I've tried

```
Shift.remove({
        _id: req.body.id
    }, function(err, count){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({success: false, message:'problem with id'});
        }else if(!err){
            res.json({success: true, message:count.n});
        }
    });
```

Even in this last example I can't see the count!! What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Hopefully this will help someone out there. To access the count I needed to use

```
count.result.n
```

not

```
count.n
```

Thanks anyways!

Comment: See [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~WriteOpResult).